# Scrollview not scrolling button

Tags: python, scrollview, kivy

I would like to create a  scrollable Floatlayout with dynamically created buttons (kind of paint where I can scroll the drawing board). Unfortunately, the code that I come out doesn't work and the buttons don't move while scrolling the FloatLayout. How can I attach the button to the FloatLayout?

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<Scroller>
    view: glayout
    FloatLayout:
        id: glayout
        width: 2000
        height: 2000
        size_hint: (None, None)
''')

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root=Scroller()
        return self.root

class Scroller(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scroller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        a = Button(size_hint=(None,None), width=200, height=200)
        self.ids.glayout.add_widget(a)
        a.bind(pos=self.ids.glayout.pos)

if __name__ in ('__main__'):
    app = Main()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FloatLayout` handle the size, not the position. The most simple solution is to replace your `FloatLayout` with a `RelativeLayout`, which handle size, and position is relative to the `RelativeLayout` origin.

Comment: Oh yeah. It worked. Funny thing is that I used `FloatLayout` with buttons at certain positions. But since it doesn't handle position I don't understand why it worked.